# inline-flex container with column-reverse impacting alignment of sibling inline-flex containers

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In my code, two inline flex divs sit next to each other.

In the first inline flex div, flex items were set to `flex-direction:column-reverse`. However, this affects its sibling inline flex div's position horizontally. By that I mean, the sibling flex positioned differently when the flex was set to `flex-direction: column`. I don't understand why this behaves like this.

My understanding is that `flex-direction` only controls the position of its children, i.e. flex items, and it has no effect on its sibling flex divs. But obviously this seems to be wrong. Can anyone explains why? Thanks!

```css
.flex {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: solid;
  margin: 10px;
}
.box {
  background: papayaWhip;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.column-reverse {
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
.column {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex column-reverse">
  <div class="box">item1</div>
  <div class="box">item2</div>
</div>
<div class='flex'>
  <div class="box">item1</div>
  <div class="box">item2</div>
</div>
<div class="flex column">
  <div class="box">item1</div>
  <div class="box">item2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds reasonable to expect that flex items in `column-reverse` in an `inline-flex` container would simply reverse, and *not affect the horizontal alignment* of other elements on the line.

In reality, however, this is not the case.

In an `inline-flex` container, `column-reverse` switches the direction of the flex items (as expected), *but also reverses the flow of the container (upward)*.

From your code (three inline-flex containers, with an added red border around the parent):

[image]

This doesn't seem to be a bug. The behavior is the same cross-browser (tested in Chrome, FF, IE11).

The issue is possibly the result of two factors:

1. the `vertical-align` property
2. `column-reverse` specification rules

### **`vertical-align`**

The initial value of the [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) property, which applies to inline-level elements, is `baseline`.

This is the value that is applied whether the container is `column` or `column-reverse`.

The alignment of flex item #1 doesn't change probably because (from the spec):

> [**5.1. Flex Flow Direction: the `flex-direction`
>   property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-direction-property)
>
> **`column-reverse`**
>
> Same as `column`, except the main-start and main-end directions are
>   swapped.
>
> Note: The reverse values do not reverse box ordering: like
>   writing-mode and direction, they only change the direction of flow.
>   Painting order, speech order, and sequential navigation orders are not
>   affected.

If I'm reading this correctly, `column-reverse` doesn't actually change the order of flex items. It reverses the flow of the container. This would explain the upward expansion of the first container.

---

### Solution #1

One method of resolving the problem, as described in [@NenadVracar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37747325/3597276), is to adjust the value of `vertical-align`. Switching from the default `baseline` value to `top` does the trick.

```css
.flex {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: solid;
  margin: 10px;
  vertical-align: top; /* NEW */
}
.box {
  background: papayaWhip;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.column-reverse {
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
.column {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex column-reverse">
  <div class="box">item1</div>
  <div class="box">item2</div>
</div>
<div class='flex'>
  <div class="box">item1</div>
  <div class="box">item2</div>
</div>
<div class="flex column">
  <div class="box">item1</div>
  <div class="box">item2</div>
</div>
```

---

### Solution #2

Making the parent of the `inline-flex` divs a flex container also solves the problem:

```css
body {
    display: flex;            /* NEW */
    align-items: flex-start;  /* NEW; optional; to disable equal height columns */
}

.flex {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: solid;
  margin: 10px;
}
.box {
  background: papayaWhip;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.column-reverse {
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
.column {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex column-reverse">
  <div class="box">item1</div>
  <div class="box">item2</div>
</div>
<div class='flex'>
  <div class="box">item1</div>
  <div class="box">item2</div>
</div>
<div class="flex column">
  <div class="box">item1</div>
  <div class="box">item2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer +1, i was trying to find something about this on w3.org but i couldn't, so it was my guess that `vertical-align` is the cause of this but i am still not sure.

Comment: I agree that vertical-align is the cause of this. But I've found something more bizarre which is if I change all the inline-flex to inline-block, and delete column-reverse. The baseline is on item2, i.e. the last element of content of the inline-block. However, if I change back to inline-flex and set the flex-direction to column, the baseline is on the item1. This raised another question, how is the baseline of inline-block different from inline-flex. At first, I assume these would be the same. I've found an article talked about baseline of inline-block but it doesn't mention inline-flex.

Comment: @fortrustit, `inline-block` and `inline-flex` represent different formatting contexts. Although there are [some similarities](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers), you can expect different behaviors among child elements. You probably won't find much about `inline-flex` online yet since it's relatively new (CSS3), whereas `inline-block` and `vertical-align` have been around for a long time.

Comment: I've found the something here: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-baselines. If I didn't understand it wrongly, it says the baseline is either on the first or last flex item, but it doesn't specify which item. And from the practice, it seems to take the baseline from the first element for inline-flex.

Comment: @fortrustit, on quick read I don't see anything new there. But if you found something that helps explain the issue, you should post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since default `vertical-align` is **baseline** it seems that when you change order of flex items or `column-reverse` in this case,  they are still aligned with `item1` but if you change `vertical-align` to **top** they are aligned to top, `vertical-align: middle` will also work here [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/971/)

```css
.flex {
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: solid;
  margin: 10px;
}
.box {
  background: papayaWhip;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.column-reverse {
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
.column {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex column-reverse">
  <div class="box">item1</div>
  <div class="box">item2</div>
</div>
<div class='flex'>
  <div class="box">item1</div>
  <div class="box">item2</div>
</div>
<div class="flex column">
  <div class="box">item1</div>
  <div class="box">item2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I don't set a vertical-align, it will take baseline to align the inline blocks. And in this case, the baseline seems to be on the item1 which is column-reversed. Not sure if I'm right about this. What I don't understand is that why the baseline is there. not on the item2

Comment: I am not sure but it seems that when you change order in this case  with `reverse` baseline is still on `item1`.